# Groupby a column, sort another column and assign rank to the rows in python

Tags: python, sorting, group-by

I have following dataframe 'scores' in pandas.

```
identifier  name             score
D29650  abc10   115369-52-3  0.75
D29650  abc10   115369-52-4  0.34
D29651  abc11   115369-52-5  0.25
D29651  abc11   ls-132190    0.67
D29652  abc12   me1228           1.0
D29652  abc12   me 1228          0.875
```

I would like sort the score column within each identifier and assign a rank to each entry. I am using following command to do that but not sure how to give rank.

```
score_new=scores.groupby(['identifier'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x:x.sort_values(by='score',ascending=False)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The desired output is:

```
identifier  name             score  rank
D29650  abc10   115369-52-3  0.75   1
D29650  abc10   115369-52-4  0.34   2
D29651  abc11   ls-132190    0.67   1
D29651  abc11   115369-52-5  0.25   2 
D29652  abc12   me1228           1.0    1
D29652  abc12   me 1228          0.875  2
```

Anh help here is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['rank']=df.groupby('identifier')['score'].rank(ascending=False).astype('int32')
```

Comment: Can we get the rank in absolute number? At the moment, it is in decimals. Thanks

Comment: You can do using list comprehension:

df['rank'] = [ int(i) for i in df.groupby("identifier")['score'].rank(ascending=False) ]

Comment: The above reply works well, how can I get the rank sorted as well..

Comment: @rshar , added .astype('int32') to Cast rank column , see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
df1=df1.sort_values(['Identifier'],ascending=[True,True])
df1['Score']=df1.Name!=df1.Name.shift().fillna('edit')
df1.Score=df1.groupby('ID').Score.cumsum()+1
```